# Cannot use alacritty dependency from git repository

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am trying to use `alacritty` as a dependency from Git as [stated in the docs](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/specifying-dependencies.html#specifying-dependencies-from-git-repositories). I get this error:

```
error[E0432]: unresolved import `alacritty`
 --> src\main.rs:1:5
  |
1 | use alacritty;
  |     ^^^^^^^^^ no `alacritty` external crate
```

To create the [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), create a new Cargo project using `cargo new hello_world --bin`, replace `main.rs` with:

```
use alacritty;

fn main() {
    println!("Hello world! :-)")
}
```

and `Cargo.toml` with:

```
[package]
name = "my-project"
version = "0.1.0"
authors = ["rsheink"]
edition = "2018"

# See more keys and their definitions at https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/manifest.html

[dependencies]
alacritty = { git = "https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty.git", tag = "v0.4.3" }
```

Comment: Writing here to not disturb the answer post. What I meant is alacritty itself is a working project that uses a library which you are aiming to use, so the working project may be a guide for how to use the that library

Comment: @ÖmerErden Understood. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alacritty is an executable. You cannot use executables as dependencies because they are not libraries.

As [Ömer Erden points out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62793835/cannot-use-alacritty-dependency-from-git-repository/62793933?noredirect=1#comment111047272_62793933), alacritty [uses another crate](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/blob/65bff1878ff68698da021b4d5aa00d1cfad41d0a/alacritty/Cargo.toml#L12) called [alacritty_terminal](https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/tree/master/alacritty_terminal). Perhaps that's what you are looking for? If not, you may wish to open an issue with the developers explaining your need and suggesting a way to reorganize the code.

Comment: I just need to use some structs from the `alacritty` crate. I dont think its a problem the fact that `alacritty ` is an executable. The `https://github.com/myfreeweb/galacritty` project does it successfully (but with a very old version of `alacritty`).

Comment: @RefaelSheinker *The galacritty project does it successfully (but with a very old version of alacritty* — yes, because 2 years ago, [the alacritty crate was a library](https://github.com/myfreeweb/alacritty/blob/d8a8fb86be2257877a1219e820b690cbc5a38fde/src/lib.rs)

Comment: Damn... You are right. Thank you very much @Shepmaster. I consider the question resolved.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker btw if it benefits the new version of executable project is using an internal library project as dependency, you can use it from here: https://github.com/alacritty/alacritty/tree/master/alacritty_terminal

Comment: @ÖmerErden, Yes, I know about `alacritty_terminal`, the problem is, they still have not made documentation on how to use it, and I could not understand by looking at the source code (I will keep trying). Thats why I tried to do what `galacritty` did.

Comment: @RefaelSheinker since alacritty(executable) uses alacritty_terminal you can use executable as documentation like you did with galacritty

Comment: I did not understand what do you mean by 'use executable as documentation'. Can you please explain in other words?